# Problem in installing two new updates in Windows 7 x64?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, windows-update, updates

I have Windows 7 64-bit build 7600. Today it notified me that there are two new updates for Windows 7.

Two new Windows 7 updates:

[image]

I pressed Install Updates. The updates installed successfully, but I didn't receive the notification yet!

Two new Windows 7 updates notifications:

[image]

As you can see in the below image they've installed several times! I've restarted my laptop several times but the problem wasn't resolved.

[image]

What should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the updates (`msxml4-KB954430-enu.exe` , `msxml4-KB973688-enu.exe`) manually and uninstalled them by themselves.
Afterward , I restart the system.
Then, I installed the updates files that I've downloaded them manually again.
The result: Sounds my problem has been solved for the nonce and I don't receive the Windows 7 notification for installing the updates anymore.

P.S:
[Another thread about my problem in Seven Forum](http://www.sevenforums.com/windows-updates-activation/76302-two-new-updates-arent-installing.html)